# Edit livedata from non UI thread in kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am designing a application with a bluetooth connection for displaying some data that is received from the BT. I want to use androids `LiveData` for communicating between layouts and classes.

I have a dedicated (non UI) thread for managing the connection with the bluetooth adapter that is responsible for receiving and sending data. I now have a problem because I cannot edit the `LiveData` from that thread. I have the following code for editing `LiveData`:

```
class ConnectThread(device: BluetoothDevice): Thread()
{
 ...
 private lateinit var model: MainViewModel
 override fun run() {
       model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
       model.frontleft.postValue("hello")
    ...
    }
 }
```

I can edit the `LiveData` with the upper code in my activity with a layout (UI) without a problem. But in my Connect thread I get the following error on the `.of(this)` section of the model code:
[error .of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soNM2.png)

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
   val frontleft: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
       MutableLiveData<String>()
   }
}
```

I have made quite a research about my problem but cannot find my answer. Is it because I want to edit the LiveData from non UI thread/fregment/activity? or because the Thread is running on a different part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

this points to current `context` so if your code are in fragment or Activity you can access it's `context` like this `this@YourFragmentName`, `this@YuorActivityName` you can also check `ViewModelProviders` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders)

`ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)` change this here

Comment: Whivh activity name do I add after this@ ? The one that the ViewModel was created in or? So I would need to do: `model = ViewModelProviders.of(this@activity).get(MainViewModel::class.java)`

Comment: yes the one which are associated with the `ViewModel`

Comment: So I've got a file "BluetoothService.kt" in which i have the functions `class ConnectThread...` and  `class MainViewModel`... but cannot acces it.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(model::class.java) internally uses a retainFragment. You need to send the value to the constructor someway or set a public observable property to set a property from the thread and use that property in the viewmodel.

`var myObservable by Delegates.Observables(""){_,_,_ -> "hello"}`

something like this

Comment: It doesn't use Retained Fragment ever since you don't need to extend `LifecycleActivity`. It uses non-configuration instance.